# How do I use ON CHANGE?

Tags: open-source, lsfusion

I am trying to use the formula

```
ON CHANGE { INPUT x = STRING LIST name(DimNomenkl s1) ACTIONS 'myaction' { MESSAGE 'current line : ' + x; } DO {....}}
```

without `ACTIONS` everything is as expected. there is an X in the field to clear. but with `ACTIONS` it just doesn't show up.
And another question `ACTIONS` - isn't it possible to have more than one button? What is wrong with my syntax?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1770)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1134)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.parseKeyStrokeOptions(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:2304)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.lambda$7(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:2297)
    at lsfusion.base.col.implementations.simple.SingletonSet.mapListValues(SingletonSet.java:428)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.getContextListEntity(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:2295)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.addScriptedInputAProp(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:2362)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.inputActionDefinitionBody(LsfLogicsParser.java:30917)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.recursiveExtendContextActionDB(LsfLogicsParser.java:23854)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.recursiveContextActionDB(LsfLogicsParser.java:23736)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.actionDefinitionBody(LsfLogicsParser.java:23655)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.keepContextFlowActionDefinitionBody(LsfLogicsParser.java:23335)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.listActionDefinitionBody(LsfLogicsParser.java:31831)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.listTopContextDependentActionDefinitionBody(LsfLogicsParser.java:23159)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formActionDeclaration(LsfLogicsParser.java:9686)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formActionObject(LsfLogicsParser.java:7704)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formPropertyOptionsList(LsfLogicsParser.java:6598)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formMappedPropertiesList(LsfLogicsParser.java:7396)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formPropertiesList(LsfLogicsParser.java:5981)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.formStatement(LsfLogicsParser.java:1750)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statement(LsfLogicsParser.java:997)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.statements(LsfLogicsParser.java:705)
    at lsfusion.server.language.LsfLogicsParser.script(LsfLogicsParser.java:659)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptParser.initParseStep(ScriptParser.java:61)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.parseStep(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:5284)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.initMainLogic(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:244)
    at lsfusion.server.logics.controller.init.InitMainLogicTask.runInnerTask(InitMainLogicTask.java:28)
    at lsfusion.server.language.ScriptingLogicsModule.runInit(ScriptingLogicsModule.java:303)
    at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.controller.init.GroupModuleTask.runTask(GroupModuleTask.java:20)
    at lsfusion.server.physics.dev.module.controller.init.GroupModuleTask.runTask(GroupModuleTask.java:1)
    at lsfusion.server.base.task.GroupSingleTask$1.run(GroupSingleTask.java:67)
    at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task.proceed(Task.java:154)
    at lsfusion.server.base.task.Task$1.aspectRun(Task.java:112)
    at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$AspectRunnable.run(ExecutorFactory.java:475)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at lsfusion.server.base.controller.thread.ExecutorFactory$ClosableDaemonThreadFactory$ClosableThread.run(ExecutorFactory.java:554)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the first part of my question I've solved to use this expression:

```
INPUT x = DimNomenkl LIST name(x) ACTIONS 'myaction' { MESSAGE 'current string : ' + x; }
```

but how can I add 'myaction' instead of standard buttons?

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).